# PHP - Why do you need 'x' permissions on a directory to read file stats?

Tags: php

I'm trying to work out why I need `x` permissions for `others` on a directory to read the stats of the files within it.

this is my folder:

```
   4 drw-r--r-x    2 root     root         4.0k Dec  7 17:40 file_host
```

When the permissions are set so `x` is assigned to others I can read the files `filemtime` etc without issue. If I remove the x then I get:

```
Warning: filemtime(): Stat failed for /file_host/file1234.zip (errno=13 - Permission denied)
```

The permission on the files in the directory are:

```
9684 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         9.4M Dec  7 17:40 file1234.zip
```

As soon as I add `x` to the folder it all works. The web user isn't root and doesn't have any root privileges.

Why do you need `x` to execute the file to read it's values ?

Any way around this ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of...http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work  The execute bit is what allows others to cd into the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute `x` bit is what allows a user to descend into a directory. The way your folder is owned, you require execute bit on the `other` portion of the permissions to allow the `www-data / apache` user to descend into the directory. If you run `chown root:www-data` and then remove the `x` bit on the `other` portion you will notice this will continue to work without giving all other users on the OS access to the directory.